# How to get exception thrown during state transition using spring state machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I am trying to understand, how an exception thrown by an action during a state transition is possible. I‘ve this simple state machine configured:

```
transitions
    .withExternal()
    .source(State.A1)
    .target(State.A2)
    .event(Event.E1)
    .action(executeAnActionThrowingAnException())
```

In my service class, I injected my state machine and send this event E1:

```
@Service
public class MyService() {

    @Autowired
    private StateMachine<State, Event> stateMachine;

    public void executeMyLogic() {
        stateMachine.start()
        stateMachine.sendEvent(Event.E1);
        // how to get thrown exception here
    }
}
```

In my service I just want to know, if and why my state machine wasn‘t able to reached State.A2. Because a thrown exception is fetched by Spring state machine, I am not able to get any response after sending the event. But the state machine hasn‘t any error, which means that

```
stateMachine.hasStateMachineError()
```

will return false. So, how can I get the information in my service, that something went wrong and more importantly what?

I appriciate your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For [transitions exceptions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-config-transition-actions-errorhandling), there's an overload for the actions method available in the [`TransitionConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/configurers/TransitionConfigurer.html#action-org.springframework.statemachine.action.Action-org.springframework.statemachine.action.Action-)

```
action(Action<S,E> action, Action<S,E> error)
```

This means you can specify and additional action to be triggered, if there's an exception raised during the transition. The exception is available from the `StateContext` passed to the action.

When your error action is triggered, you can retrieve the exception with:

```
context.getException();
```

Inside the error action you can do a couple of things to deal with the exception:

- do logging of the exception and the context
- transition to some error state
- clear the context and transition to the same state and try to execute some retry logic
- add some additional info to the context and return the context to the caller

For example:

```
context.getVariables().put("hasError", true); 
context.getVariables().put("error", ex);
```

And in your service(caller) you handle the exception as you like, for example:

```
public void executeMyLogic() {
    stateMachine.start()
    stateMachine.sendEvent(Event.E1);
    if (stateMachine.getExtendedState().getVariables().containsKey("hasError") {
      throw (RuntimeException)stateMachine.getExtendedState().getVariables().get("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: I first thought there must be another way. But, obviously there is not. So, I use your suggested way and it's working. Thanks.

Comment: I am sending state events in a lot of places on my project so I don't want to put that control every place. is there any appropriate way to do it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can think about utilizing a transition to an error state and managing everything there, but depends on the usecase really.

Comment: @SametBaskıcı you can have a common method that sends the event and checks for the extended state for error and throw an exception if needed. In that way, the check can be minimized to a single method.